# scanf - program waits for another like?

Tags: c++, printf, scanf

In the following program, I expect that after entering a word and hitting the enter key I should immediately see the message `printf`ed out. However, it doesn't happen until I enter some other random word. Why is that?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

char tictac[17];

int main() 
{
    scanf("%s\n", tictac);


    printf("%s\n", tictac);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't use `using namespace std;` in C. You even shouldn't use it in C++.

Comment: @sobol6803 this was written in C++ just as a quick demonstration not an actual code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**: with `scanf("%s\n", tictac);` you are asking to read a string, ignore all blank characters after it and then a read a new line. The problem is since all blanks are ignored by the first one there should be a at least one non blank character between the first <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the second <kbd>Enter</kbd> (hence the need for some garbage *non-blank* input before the second <kbd>Enter</kbd> is accepted.).

---

Here is an example usage of  \n with scanf.

```
char x, y;
scanf("%c", &x); 
scanf("%c", &y);
printf("%c %c", x,y);
```

with this code you will see that entering one character and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will directly go to the `printf` statement. This is because the second scanf reads the carriage return (which itself is a character) in to y.

```
scanf("\n%c", &y);  // This is recommended to do if you have a sequence of scanfs (but not on the first one).
```

With this one the stray carriage return will be ignored (or matched) with `\n`. And the correct character will be read to y.

---

Now when we come to your code

```
scanf("%s\n", tictac);
```

`%s` tells `scanf` to read until it finds a `blank character` (`space, tab or new line`) and then **here is the catch ignore all blank spaces till a non blank space character is met**. So your `scanf` will ignore the <kbd>Enter</kbd> you pressed when you entered the string. **And any blank character that follows it** (*try entering spaces on the second line and press enter.*)

Which means this will work just fine (unlike the char version)

```
scanf("%s", tictac);
scanf("%s", tictac2);
```

---

Actually on [Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/67879)

> Because "%s" causes the library to read the input string until it
>   finds some white space, the equivalent format specifier is
>   "%[^\0x20\t\n]", which instructs the library to read the string until
>   it encounters a space character (\0x20), a tab character (\t), or a
>   newline character (\n).

**However since you have explicitly asked `scanf` to match `\n`**

```
scanf("%s\n", tictac);
         ^^
```

**it will wait until it gets another `\n` (after a non blank character) because the first one one was used by `%s`.**

Comment: Could you please clarify the scanf more? If I get it right scanf("%s\n",var) first reads the string (until whitespace) into the var and ignores the whitespaces immediately after the string(so even the enter I hit). Then it waits for the new line "\n"?  PS: I'm using cstdio for performance and low RAM consumption.

Comment: @Novellizator it doesn't really mean new line here. It means wait for `carriage return` (the enter on keyboard ) after each input. Try this `scanf("%d %d %d", &x,&y,&z); ` and `scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &x,&y,&z); ` and you will see the difference.

Comment: tried the example above - I cannot see the differece... in both cases I tried to write all the numbers in one line a also hitting the enter key enter every single value. In neither of the cases did it differ.

Comment: @Novellizator See the edit I think this explains it in more detail.

Comment: "%s tells scanf to read until it finds a blank character ... and then ... ignore all blank spaces till a non blank space character is met." mis-leads.  The `%s` first scans for whitespace, without storing them.  Then it scans for non-whitespace, storing them.  stores a NUL, then stops.  It is the _following_ `\n` that then scans for whitespace, not storing anything.  This continues until a non-whitespace is met.  Note: whitespace is _more_ than ' ',\t,\n.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the `\n` from your [*scanf*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) call.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good explanation of scanf [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/37537-how-to-use-scanf-in-c/). In your case, you should remove the \n from your scanf function.